# /usr/loca/bin does not exist on OS X until MATLAB install

Tags: macos

I just installed a fresh copy of Yosemite on a formatted hard drive, I did not migrate any data over to it and am starting fresh.

I am installing MATLAB for the first time on the device and when I was about to install it prompted me with:

> /usr/local/bin does not exist, would like like to create it?

I was worried because MATLAB isn’t the first program I have installed, I had already installed Thunderbird, VLC, Skype, and a few other apps. But MATLAB was the first app I am trying to install after moving my home directory to my second internal hard drive.

All I did was create a second admin user, copied my home directory to my second internal HDD (from my SSD which i want to reserve for applications and OS), and then pointed my main user home directory to the copied folder on the HDD. Then I deleted my Home folder on my internal SSD leaving only the one on my internal HDD. This should not affect `/usr/local/bin`.

So I am wondering, do the other apps I use simply never needed to install any files to `/usr/local/bin` and so it was never made? Is `/usr/local/bin` not created on OS X until it needs to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/usr/local/bin` directory is a Unix/Linux specific directory created for the explicit use of locally installed system binaries. Meaning binaries that are not part of the core Unix/Linux install base.

The apps you mention—Thunderbird, VLC, Skype, etc…—are self contained apps that simply operate completely out of the `/Applications` folder with only some files references in the user `~/Libaray/` directory and that is it.

As for why MATLAB would install items in `/usr/local/bin`? Easy: It is far more complex a setup than a traditional application. Thus it has to install binaries & related libraries closer the Unix/Linux core. And why is that key? Easy again: The creators/maintainers of MATLAB clearly support Windows as well as Linux & Mac. From a programming/maintenance standpoint it makes more sense for them to derive the Mac version from the Linux setup than to maintain a completely independent codebase.

Meaning, it’s tough enough to manage programming code across Windows and Macs let alone, Windows, Macs and Linux. So by leveraging the fact that Mac OS X is simply a flavor of Unix, and Linux/Unix are basically cousins it makes it easier for them to balance the Mac/Linux code on a common Unix base and then branch off with specific adjustments more particular to Mac and Linux setups.

Which is all to say you should not worry at all about `/usr/local/bin` having to be created for the first time. It’s normal, not an issue and if you don’t create it now chances are sometime in the future you might download some program that is more Unix/Linux oriented and will have to create `/usr/local/bin` anyway.

A nice explanation on the history of `/usr/local` hierarchy [can be found here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4187).